# BasicHttpBinding recommended settings

Tags: c#, wsdl

I have a memory leak (or v.high memory usage) in one of my processes, and I believe it may be due to incorrectly/poorly settings in the BasicHttpBinding it uses when constructing SOAP clients.

In particular I am curious as to how to know what to `MaxBufferSize`, `MaxBufferPoolSize`, and `MaxReceivedMessageSize` to on the binding.  Is there any reason to suggest they should be changed from the default settings?

The current code does this,

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.MaxBufferSize = 5000000; // (5,000,000)
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 5000000;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5000000;

binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 500000; // (500,000)
```

I guess my questions are:

- Is there any chance these values are causing high memory usage or a leak?
- Should I / would it be safe to change these back to default?
- Would there be any downside to just setting `.MaxReceivedMessageSize = long.MaxValue` and `.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue`?

I can confirm I know the `MaxStringContentLength` needs to be increased from default due to some exceptionally long strings being received, however I have no idea why the buffers are being set to these sizes.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please define "very high memory usage".

> Is there any chance these values are causing high memory usage or a leak?

I don't think so, it's more logical to suspect the service implementation than the WCF binding, which really is just a bit of plumbing that receives the message and passes it on to your code.

> Should I / would it be safe to change these back to default?

You can try.

> Would there be any downside to just setting .MaxReceivedMessageSize = long.MaxValue and .MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue?

The [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.maxreceivedmessagesize%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says:

> The size of the messages that can be received on the wire by services [...] is bounded by **the amount of memory allocated for each message**.

So I guess setting it to a few gigs is not going to improve your service's memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  "very high memory usage" means the service starts at about 100MB and over the course of a week or 2 rises above 1GB.  Other services I have which also use these bindings (but with other services) happily idle around the 100MB mark.